# Moving application windows from one workspace to another by dragging in the workspace chooser?

Tags: applet, workspaces

The old workspace chooser allowed you to move application windows between workspaces by dragging them around in the workspace chooser.  I much prefer that to the new workspace chooser's method of dragging them off the side of the screen. For one thing, in order to drag a window from a different workspace into the one I'm working in, I have to switch workspaces twice and unmaximize a maximized window with the new method, where with the old I simply had to drag.  Is there anyway to get this old functionality back in Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Plus one on this - It's a shame that even though the workspace switcher says "Click to start dragging" it doesn't actually do this anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off desktop effects.  This works fine with Metacity in 10.10, and I'd be really surprised if it was removed for one release.

Comment: It works with Metacity & Bluetile in 10.04, so certainly seems to be a compiz issue.  (IIRC compiz doesn't use workspaces, technically, but something that looks/behaves more or less the same?)

Comment: Yep, Compiz uses viewports.  It's all one workspace (you're just seeing different parts of it).  If you have windows on multiple viewports in Compiz then switch to Metacity, they all collapse onto one Metacity workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a hotkey for moving windows between viewports--that can be helpful.

Compiz also has the "Expo" function, which I think might be up your ally. It zooms out, and shows you every viewport. You can drag windows between them, and double click on one to go to it.